# I cannot execute this query SQL

Tags: sql

Show how to define the view student grades (ID, GPA) giving the grade-point average of each student; recall that we used a relation grade_points (grade, points) to get the numeric points associated with a letter grade. Make sure your view definition correctly handles the case of null values for the grade attribute of the takes relation.

```
create view student_grades(ID, GPA) as 
select ID, credit_ points / decode(credit sum, 0, NULL, credit_sum) 
from ((select ID, sum(decode(grade, NULL, 0, credits)) as credit_sum, 
sum(decode(grade, NULL, 0, credits*points)) as credit_points 
from(takes natural join course) natural left outer join grade points group by ID) 
union 
select ID, NULL 
from student 
where ID not in (select ID from takes));
```

Can someone please correct this code?

Comment: Please read [Why should I tag my RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: And please explain *why* you "cannot execute the query"

Comment: Please show table descriptions. Which column belongs to which table? Which are the tables' keys? There are syntax errors in your query (see the blanks in `credit_ points / decode(credit sum`). Please tag your request with your DBMS (Oracle probably). You should not use natural joins. They are very dangerous and should never have been invented in my opinion. Just make it a rule to never ever use them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you decode() and sum() parameters a mixed up !! Decode ask for 2 arguments
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/decode().php

Comment: Consider adding an example that would help answer the question directly, or put this in as a comment instead.

Comment: The OP has not mentioned their DBMS yet. It's probably Oracle, where `DECODE` is something entirely different from `DECODE` in MySQL. w3ressource is notorious for being an unreliable source, by the way. (At least it used to be so, and I doubt this has changed much.)

Comment: I cant edit the post and global commentary im in a new account... But yeah...

@ThorstenKettner You probably right XD